# Python split lines from file into two separate lists

Tags: python, string, list, binary

I am reading in a file where every line contains a binary string, like `01000000 00001000 00000000 11111111`, and a number, 0 or 1, two spaces after the binary string that corresponds to that binary string. So an example line looks like:
`01000000 00001000 00000000 11111111  0`

I want my program to output this:
`['01000000', '00001000', '00000000', '11111111']`
`['0']`

This is my code right now:

```
def main():
f=open('file.txt', 'r').readlines()
for line in f:
    words = line.split("  ", 1)
    wordsList=list(words)
    for i in range(0, len(wordsList)-1):
        binary = wordsList[i:i+1]
        link = wordsList[i+1:i+2]
        print(binary)
        print(link) 
main()
```

Right now, when I run it, the program returns this:
`['01000000 00001000 00000000 1111111']`
`['0']`

What am I missing here?

Comment: Just to clarify, we aren't talking about actual binary data, just string representations of 0's and 1's??

Comment: `.split( )` returns a list there's no need for the `wordsList = list(words)` you can just have `binary = words[0]` and `link = words[1]`, but then you need to `print(binary.split(" "))` if you want that string to divvy up the individual binary strings.

Answer (score 1):

You should split the entire line, then slice off the final number.

To split the line, use `line.split()`. The default parameters will work just fine.

To slice the resulting array, `line[:-1]` grabs all of the elements up to, but not including, the final one. `line[-1:]` grabs the final element.

Sample program:

```
def main():
    with open('file.txt') as f:
        for line in f:
            line = line.split()
            binary = line[:-1]
            link = line[-1:]
            print(binary)
            print(link)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: I didn't think of you as stupid when I wrote the response. You just needed a fresh pair of eyes looking at the problem. Don't beat yourself up.